# AWS Step Function - Map - waiting for all iterations to finish

Tags: amazon-web-services, state-machine, aws-step-functions

Is it possible to wait until **ONLY ONE** iteration has been completed and then move on with the flow? Or must you always wait for **ALL** iterations to complete before moving on?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All, not one.  The [Map State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) ends when all iterations have completed or any iteraton has failed.